# How to package grpc-web generated code into npm package

Tags: javascript, go, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-web

I have protofiles defined inside a go module and publish this module so servers and go-clients can reference the generated code. Now I also want to have grpc-web client to communicate with the server. grpc-web generates `ts` and `js` files, but inorder to use this in browser I need to package this as npm module or copy the generated code into browser repo manually which I do not want to do. What is the standard practice here?

Is there a good solution to package npm & go module from proto files.

Update: I ended up copying over the generated ts/js files into desired location as part of my standard build. Since I have a mono repo this is sufficient right now. Kind of straight forward and also source controlled. Not sure if there is a better idomatic way.